# How to replace camera input stream for Android?

Tags: java, android, webcam

The scenario:

I want to replace the Android input stream of the camera with just a picture.

So when I run any application, that uses the input stream of the camera, it uses the previously set picture instead.

The solution:

I thought about using the software ManyCam. With ManyCam you can change the camera input stream to basically whatever you like.

So I installed ManyCam on my Windows 10 system and I also installed Bluestacks Android Emulator. Bluestacks uses the webcam input stream of the laptop, so when I overwrite the input stream with a picture with ManyCam, all the apps in Bluestacks should use the overwritten input stream.

The problem:

When I use any app in Bluestacks, instead of showing the overwritten input stream from ManyCam, the apps access the webcam itself and show the standard input of the webcam.

I also tried to install ManyCam inside of Bluestacks, but when I choose a picture as video input source, the other apps still access the webcam and show the standard input.

I also tried to use ManyCam on my Android test device, but the Android phone also uses the standard cam input, not the input from ManyCam.

The solution:

I need a way to overwrite the standard Android cam input with my custom cam input (the picture). I think there should be an easy solution for this.

I have basic coding skills in Python, but I have a good understanding for overall coding aspects. I know all the concepts. I would need a low code solution to fix this problem. If it is not possible with ManyCam, I am of course also open to other solutions.

Comment: "I think there should be an easy solution for this" -- only if you consider creating a custom build of the Android OS to be "easy".

Comment: Why do I have to create a custom build of the OS?

Comment: You wrote: "I need a way to overwrite the standard Android cam input with my custom cam input". That will require a custom build of the OS AFAIK. *Maybe* you can do something lighter-weight on a rooted Android device, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

Disable your webcam driver, so BlueStack will not be able to acces your webcam

Answer (score -2):

There is now new many cam abilities and you can do it by connecting your ohonhonee via the app to a windows pc

Comment: which app exactly?